# Set two values to a dropdownlist from db

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist inside a detailsview. Right now I'm using DataTextField for displaying the text, but now I wanna add one more textvalue.

My aspx:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="nFuturesId"
                            DataSourceID="FutureCommodityODS" DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting"
                            SkinID="detailsviewSkin" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Future" SortExpression="strFutureName">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <BrummerComp:SortableDropDownList ID="DropDownListFuturesInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="FutureNameODS"
                                        DataTextField="strFutureName" DataValueField="nFuturesId" SkinID="BCdropdownlistSkin">
                        </BrummerComp:SortableDropDownList>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>               
</asp:DetailsView>
```

I have one more column that I wanna add to the DataTextField called strFutureShortName. I would like it to be something like this:

```
DataTextField="strFutureName, strFutureShortName"
```

My idea was that I could get the DropDownList in my Page_Load and trying to add the values from there:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownListFuturesInsert");
        ddl.DataTextField = "strFutureName"; //Here I would like "strFutureName" + "strFutureShortName"
    }
```

But this code isn't working (when I have removed attribute DataTextField in .aspx).

Does anyone know how I could do this?

EDIT:

I think I found where the DDL is binded, it's using tablemapping like this:

```
global::System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping tableMapping = new global::System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping();
tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("strFutureName", "strFutureName");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly add multiple value in text field. You have to create a seperate property for that for your entity and then add this as a datetext field.

For example.Let's take person class

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName 
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to set that FullName as datasource.

```
<BrummerComp:SortableDropDownList ID="DropDownListFuturesInsert" runat="server"    DataSourceID="FutureNameODS"
                                    DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="PersonId" SkinID="BCdropdownlistSkin">
                    </BrummerComp:SortableDropDownList>
```

Comment: So it's not a class like that...sorry but I'm quite new to this :)

Comment: what is that tableMapping? DDL is not bound with that It is bound with object datasource you are using and list which you are generating for object data source. Can you paste your object datasource coding also?

Comment: Updated again, DataTableMapping, was a type error from my side